# Adding characters to string in r

Tags: r

So I have a character column with each row looking something like this:

```
aa  Alice
bb  peter
cc  Jon
```

And I would like to add a dot after the first two letters. so get something like

```
aa. Alice
bb. peter
cc. Jon
```

Please help, still not very familiar with string functions in r.

Thanks a Bunch

Comment: use: `gsub("  ", ".  ", str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if you want to add a `.` after the first word and keep everything else, you can use capture groups in `gsub`:

```
gsub("(^\\w+)(.*)", "\\1.\\2", chars)

#[1] "aa.  Alice" "bb.  peter" "cc.  Jon"
```

In this case the `(^\\w+)` matches a word of any length at the beginning of the string. We grab this and put a `.` after it with `\\1.`.

---

Alternatively, if you want to always paste a `.` after the first two characters you could use a similar idea:

```
sub("([[:alpha:]]{2})(.*)", "\\1.\\2", chars)
```